# which kernel do I install in debian?

Tags: debian, debian-installer

I am installing debian onto a vm and I am at a screen asking me to choose a kernel to install. I have 5 options:

- linux-image-5.10.0.20-686
- linux-image-5.10.0.20-686-pae
- linux-image-686
- linux-image-686-pae
- none

which one do I install?

Comment: For a 64-bit x86 VM it would be normal to install `linux-image-amd64`. The `686` and `i686` are for 32bit x86 VMs. Almost all x86 made since 2010 are 64 bit, although they can run in 32bit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PAE means [Physical Hardware Extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension).

Use it if your CPU architecture is 32 bits and your VM has more than 4 Gb of RAM (by default x86 doesn't support more than this amout of RAM).

If it is not the case, I would recommend the `linux-image-686`, but without more info about your config it is hard to say more...

Answer (score 0):

Normally it makes sense to use the generic package (without the version number). When upgraded packages become available they will
be automatically used.

You do not mention what VM software you are using.

If you created a VM with a 32bit architecture the generic package 'linux-image-686' makes sense.

If you instead create a 64bit architecture VM the generic package 'linux-image-amd64' should be available and used.